# Fragment onDestroyView() is being called before animation completed

Tags: android, android-fragments

At the request of a client, I'm attempting to emulate an "iOS UINavigationController-style" right-to-left push, left-to-right pop animation using Android's `FragmentManager` / `FragmentTransaction` framework and the `setCustomAnimations()` method to achieve the transition animations.

Everything is working well, except when popping a fragment off the back stack - the `onDestroyView()` is being called immediately on the fragment being popped, and the fragment's child views are immediately removed from the layout.

This means that there is a flash of black (the popped fragment's background colour) before the preceding fragment finishes animating into view, which is kinda ugly.

Any ideas on how I can force the popped fragment to retain it's view hierarchy until the transition animation has completed?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem.

I found that ondestoryview() was called when animations started and ondestory() was called when finished.

So I moved some code from ondestoryview() to ondestory().

Another solution:
add these code in your onDestoryView():

```
View v = getView();
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
v.draw(c);
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(ProviderFactory.getContext().getResources(), b);
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container).setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
} else {
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container).setBackground(bd);
}
```